# predicate logic and complex numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i came across with a problem in my discrete math course exercises and i could not solve it. 
Here is the question :

$$\forall x\exists y (P(x,y))\iff \exists y\forall x(P(x,y))$$

For any predicate P(x,y) is always true?
by the way , x and y are complex numbers .

Comment: How well does it work if $P(x,y)$ means $x=y$, for example?

Comment: Note that this doesn't really depend on any properties of complex numbers (except that there's more than one of them).

Comment: There is no information about P(x,y) means x = y . I think there is something with quantifiers .

Comment: x @cscap: You're being asked whether it is true for _every_ predicate $P$. One of the predicates it has to work for is $=$. Now, _is_ it true for $=$?

Comment: Yes, but start with examples for $P$ helps you understand what you are trying to prove. @cscaptainblack

Comment: (Of course there's _some_ predicate that makes it true; e.g. if $P(x,y)$ means $x+y=x+y+1$, which is false for all $x$ and $y$, then both sides of the $\Leftrightarrow$ are false, so the entire thing is true).